# get table model from table with unknown rows and columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable, resultset, tablemodel

I know how to get a simple TableModel from a table that I knew.

But I wanted to know how to get a TableModel from a table which I don't know its columns and rows details.

Isn't there a way to get the table model directly from the `ResultSet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/59-resultset-to-tablemodel

Comment: why did i use complicated tags in my searching --"

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table object, then you can a tablemodel by using `getModel()`.

Comment: -_- i want to create the table, i only have the reslutset from the statement

Comment: You mean you have data and you want to create table?